# VBA Copy to word from excel error (wdPasteText)

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, userform

We are using an Excel file for a long time, and it is working pretty file for everyone except one of my colleagues from yesterday! We need to make a report out of an Excel file and the code stops in this line for him and make the "wdPasteText" highlighted, and it is saying that the project cannot be found in the library:

```
    oDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=wdPasteText, _
    DisplayAsIcon:=False
```

I checked all the preferences in the VBA module, and we have the same check boxes. Do you have any idea that what is the cause for that error? Is there any way that I can declare wdPasteText in the code?

The previous error from him was in wdPageBreak, and after I defined it as a constant it worked. I wonder that I can do it for this one as well. Looking further in the code, I am afraid we get similar error for  "wdPasteEnhancedMetafile"

Comment: Put `Option Explicit` on top.

Comment: Are you using Latebinding or Early Binding? Also what do you mean when you say `except one of my colleagues from yesterday!` Was it working before yesterday?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though your code project is missing a reference to the Word library. If you have been using this for some time and it has worked it has probably been edited recently in an unwise attempt to use late binding.

Just go to Tools | References and check box next to the entry for Microsoft Word.

[image: References dialog]